# Where can I find historical data for Italian weather (especially for hail storm)?

Tags: weather, historical

I need historical hailstorm data for Italian cities, day by day since 2014.

I don't mind what format the data is in (csv, xml, etc...). Having a Web API would be great as well.

Comment: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/isd may or may not be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In the event you get no other answers (or better ones), I do have an option for you. It's a little messy and 'manual', but it will work if you have no other options.

In summary, follow these steps:

1. Got to https://www.wunderground.com/history/
2. Enter a city (e.g. Rome, Italy)
3. Leave today's date as is and click on Submit
4. In the next window that appears, you will see four tabs as follows
   [image]
5. Click on the **Custom** tab at the end
6. In the following page you will have fields to enter a date range
7. In the From fields select January 1 2014
8. Click on the **Get History** button
9. After a while the page will refresh with your data. Scroll down to where the table is located starting with 1 January 2014
10. Take a note of the fact that the table has a number of columns, with the last one being for **Events**. It is in this column that you will be able to identify Hailstorms by finding the term *Hail*. For example, the first hailstorm in this example occurred on 15 November 2014.
11. Now scroll down to the very bottom of the table and click on the **Comma Delimited File** link
12. Use the generated file to import into Excel or whatever software you wish to use.

Obviously this is a little tedious. However, this site does also offer a [Weather API](https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api) that may or may not meet your needs.

Hopefully you find a better solution. Perhaps you could contact the [Italian Meteorological Service](http://www.meteoam.it/)?

Comment: Thank you. I have written to them in order to ask for historical API, because I have about 2331 cities to query for...